# Bash for-loop statement for i in {1..10} does not work

Tags: bash, ubuntu

From the online resources, the loop,

```
for num in {1..10}
do
 echo "number: $num"
done
```

should produce:

```
number: 1
number: 2
...
```

However I get the output

```
number: {1..10}
```

What is the problem? I use Ubuntu 14.04, the bash version is 4.3.11.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which shell and version?

Comment: Make sure you are in `bash`

Comment: Try to insert `#!/bin/bash` at first line of your script.

Comment: Add output of `echo $SHELLOPTS` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

With bash.

Enable expanding of braces:

```
set -o braceexpand
```

Disable:

```
set +o braceexpand
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you can't solve it could be:

```
for num in `seq 1 10`; do
  echo "number: $num"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ./yourfilename.sh
or
use
bash yourfilename.sh